# Adding JSF 2 composite component at runtime from backing bean

Tags: jsf, runtime, loading, composite-component

Edited question...

Hello,

I would like to load a .xhtml file of my composite component from a backing bean, and add it to the page dynamically. The name of the .xhtml file comes form a variable.

Ex.:

```
public MyBean (){

    String componentFile = "myCompositeComponent.xhtml"

    public String addComponentToPage(){

          //how do that?...

          return null;
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: To the point, the question makes no utter sense. [Composite components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) exist of XHTML only, not of Java code. It's entirely unclear how the code of `CCPageLoader` look like, so it's impossible to guess/understand what you *actually* mean. This question will remain unanswered until you fix the terminology and/or supply some code so that the question is better understood.

Comment: Hi BalusC, what I would like to do: load the xhtml file of the composite component and add it to the page. This needs to be done by the backing bean of the page. Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically or dynamically create a composite component in JSF 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370184/how-to-programmatically-or-dynamically-create-a-composite-component-in-jsf-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's *not* possible. A composite component is template-based and can only be used in views. Your best bet is to repeat exactly the JSF code which you've originally written in the composite component in the model. Better would be to create a full worthy [`@FacesComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/FacesComponent.html) class which extends [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html), complete with a [`@FacesRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/render/FacesRenderer.html). True, it's a tedious and opaque job, but this way you'll end up with a component which is reuseable in both the view and the model by a single code line.

An -ugly- alternative is to place all possible components in the view and use the `rendered` attribute.

```
<my:component1 rendered="#{bean.myComponentType == 'component1'}" />
<my:component2 rendered="#{bean.myComponentType == 'component2'}" />
<my:component3 rendered="#{bean.myComponentType == 'component3'}" />
...
```

Wrap this if necessary in a Facelets tag file so that it can be hidden away and reused in several places.

Comment: thanks a lot! So I can understand that composite component in JSF are really differents from "Composite Component" in other languages/frameworks like .ascx file (.net) or .mxml (Flex)... I read articles and documents on that, but this aspect was not enough clear.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://forums.java.net/node/701640 There are a few approaches researched/described by the user 'lexi'. Despite of difficulties he had, he states that he came up with a working solution (see the second last post) which is unfortunately a bit cryptic. The last message describes another, simpler alternative, also suggested by Ed Burns. However, according to the same post it's not working. Any thoughts on these approaches?

Comment: @Tuukka: Interesting. But that's hacky and not provided by JSF API (and thus JSF-impl specific).

Comment: Typo in @FacesCompnent

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you want to add a composite component from a backing bean. I guess you want to make it visible dynamically in case of an event, but for that there is AJAX reRender.

For example you can do the following:

```
<h:panelGroup id="composite" rendered="#{myBean.renderComponent}">
    <my:compositecomponent/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The `renderComponent` property stores a `boolean` value. You can switch that value and reRender `composite` with for e.g. Richfaces's `<a4j:commandLink>`.

Hope that helps, Daniel

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm able to do that, but I don't know the name of the component, the name comes from a String variable...

Comment: I think what you want to do goes against basic design conceptions. I think you should think about another method of solving your problem.

Comment: It's easy to come up with cases where you want to do this (call composite components from Java code). For example, consider a component that will build long/complex DOM structure. Normally, you would implement that as a composite component, but in some cases they aren't just flexible enough so you resort to extending UIComponent and using ResponseWriter. However, it would be nicer to do the complex logic inside the UIComponent and yet call a composite component (a template) to actually build the (most of the) UI. It's bad that when you switch to Java code, you are stuck with UIComponents :/