# How to programmatically or dynamically create a composite component in JSF 2

Tags: java, dynamic, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I need to programmatically create composite components in JSF 2. After few days of searching and experiments I figured out this method (highly inspired by Lexi at java.net):

```
/**
 * Method will attach composite component to provided component
 * @param viewPanel parent component of newly created composite component
 */
public void setComponentJ(UIComponent viewPanel) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    viewPanel.getChildren().clear();

    // load composite component from file
    Resource componentResource = context.getApplication().getResourceHandler().createResource("whatever.xhtml", "components/form");
    UIComponent composite = context.getApplication().createComponent(context, componentResource);

    // push component to el
    composite.pushComponentToEL(context, composite);
    boolean compcompPushed = false;
    CompositeComponentStackManager ccStackManager = CompositeComponentStackManager.getManager(context);
    compcompPushed = ccStackManager.push(composite, CompositeComponentStackManager.StackType.TreeCreation);

    // Populate the component with value expressions 
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    composite.setValueExpression("value", application.getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(
            context.getELContext(), "#{stringValue.value}",
            String.class));

    // Populate the component with facets and child components (Optional)
    UIOutput foo = (UIOutput) application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    foo.setValue("Foo");
    composite.getFacets().put("foo", foo);
    UIOutput bar = (UIOutput) application.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    bar.setValue("Bar");
    composite.getChildren().add(bar);

    // create composite components Root
    UIComponent compositeRoot = context.getApplication().createComponent(UIPanel.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    composite.getAttributes().put(Resource.COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY, componentResource);
    compositeRoot.setRendererType("javax.faces.Group");
    composite.setId("compositeID");

    try {
        FaceletFactory factory = (FaceletFactory) RequestStateManager.get(context, RequestStateManager.FACELET_FACTORY);
        Facelet f = factory.getFacelet(componentResource.getURL());
        f.apply(context, compositeRoot); //<==[here]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Error creating composite component!!", e);
    }
    composite.getFacets().put(
            UIComponent.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME, compositeRoot);

    // attach composite component to parent componet
    viewPanel.getChildren().add(composite);

    // pop component from el
    composite.popComponentFromEL(context);
    if (compcompPushed) {
        ccStackManager.pop(CompositeComponentStackManager.StackType.TreeCreation);
    }
}
```

Problem is that this code works for me only when `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `PRODUCTION` (It took me all day to figure this out). If `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` is set to `DEVELOPMENT` Exception is thrown on marked point (`<==[here]`):

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /resources/components/form/pokus.xhtml @8,19 <cc:interface> Component Not Found for identifier: j_id2.getParent().  
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.InterfaceHandler.validateComponent(InterfaceHandler.java:135)  
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.InterfaceHandler.apply(InterfaceHandler.java:125)  
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)  
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)  
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:82)  
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)  
    at cz.boza.formcreator.formcore.Try.setComponentJ(Try.java:83)  
    at cz.boza.formcreator.formcore.FormCreator.<init>(FormCreator.java:40)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
```

It's some problem with parent set in `compositeRoot` component (`j_id2` is automaticaly generated ID of `compositeRoot`). Also this code is not tested thoroughly enough, so I'm not sure if I can rely on it.

I think it's very important to be able to manipulate Composite Components programmatically. Otherwise Composite Components are half useless.

Comment: After some testing I also found out, that I can't programatically nest any component (add as child) in other composite component :(.

Comment: Ok So I finaly found solution. Here you can download demo ho to programatically create Composite Components. http://confluence.highsource.org/display/Hifaces20/Dynamic+Faces+-+sample+demonstrating+dynamic+or+programmatic+UI+creation+with+JSF+2.0+and+Facelets

Comment: I tried The link now and It works. It's quiet complicated because it's whole project about programatic creation of composite components and dynamic construction of JSF pages.

Comment: The link in the answer works, but the links in the linked page which should offer a download of the source code are broken and therefore this answer is incomplete. Actually, link-only answers are strongly discouraged on Stack Exchange for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 18):

I can't explain the concrete problem in detail, but I can only observe and confirm that the approach as shown in the question is clumsy and tight coupled to Mojarra. There are `com.sun.faces.*` specific dependencies requiring Mojarra. This approach is not utilizing the standard API methods and, additionally, would not work in other JSF implementations like MyFaces.

Here's a much simpler approach utilizing standard API-provided methods. The key point is that you should use [`FaceletContext#includeFacelet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/FaceletContext.html#includeFacelet%28javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.net.URL%29) to include the composite component resource in the given parent.

```
public static void includeCompositeComponent(UIComponent parent, String libraryName, String resourceName, String id) {
    // Prepare.
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) context.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);

    // This basically creates <ui:component> based on <composite:interface>.
    Resource resource = application.getResourceHandler().createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
    UIComponent composite = application.createComponent(context, resource);
    composite.setId(id); // Mandatory for the case composite is part of UIForm! Otherwise JSF can't find inputs.

    // This basically creates <composite:implementation>.
    UIComponent implementation = application.createComponent(UIPanel.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    implementation.setRendererType("javax.faces.Group");
    composite.getFacets().put(UIComponent.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME, implementation);

    // Now include the composite component file in the given parent.
    parent.getChildren().add(composite);
    parent.pushComponentToEL(context, composite); // This makes #{cc} available.
    try {
        faceletContext.includeFacelet(implementation, resource.getURL());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new FacesException(e);
    } finally {
        parent.popComponentFromEL(context);
    }
}
```

Imagine that you want to include `<my:testComposite id="someId">` from URI `xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents"`, then use it as follows:

```
includeCompositeComponent(parent, "mycomponents", "testComposite.xhtml", "someId");
```

This has also been added to JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) as `Components#includeCompositeComponent()` (since V1.5).

---

**Update** since JSF 2.2, the `ViewDeclarationLanguage` class got a new [`createComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#createComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) method taking the taglib URI and tag name which could also be used for this purpose. So, if you're using JSF 2.2, the approach should be done as follows:

```
public static void includeCompositeComponent(UIComponent parent, String taglibURI, String tagName, String id) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent composite = context.getApplication().getViewHandler()
        .getViewDeclarationLanguage(context, context.getViewRoot().getViewId())
        .createComponent(context, taglibURI, tagName, null);
    composite.setId(id);
    parent.getChildren().add(composite);
}
```

Imagine that you want to include `<my:testComposite id="someId">` from URI `xmlns:my="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mycomponents"`, then use it as follows:

```
includeCompositeComponent(parent, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mycomponents", "testComposite", "someId");
```

Comment: Hello. I am facing the issue as well; Is the facelet dynamic creation example OK exactly for jsf 2.0? Cause I am facing NPE in this line `*.getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);`

Comment: How can we pass attirubute params?

Comment: `composite.getAttributes().put("name", value)`

Answer (score 7):

As both solutions did not work for me, i dig into the JSF implementation to find out, how the statically inserted composites are added and handled in the component tree. This is the working code i finally ended up with:

```
public UIComponent addWidget( UIComponent parent, String widget ) {
    UIComponent cc = null;
    UIComponent facetComponent = null;
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Resource resource = ctx.getApplication().getResourceHandler().createResource( widget + ".xhtml", "widgets" );
    FaceletFactory faceletFactory = (FaceletFactory) RequestStateManager.get( ctx, RequestStateManager.FACELET_FACTORY );

    // create the facelet component
    cc = ctx.getApplication().createComponent( ctx, resource );

    // create the component to be populated by the facelet
    facetComponent = ctx.getApplication().createComponent( UIPanel.COMPONENT_TYPE );
    facetComponent.setRendererType( "javax.faces.Group" );

    // set the facelet's parent
    cc.getFacets().put( UIComponent.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME, facetComponent );

    // populate the facetComponent
    try {
        Facelet facelet = faceletFactory.getFacelet( resource.getURL() );
        facelet.apply( ctx, facetComponent );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // finally add the facetComponent to the given parent
    parent.getChildren().add( cc );

    return cc;
}
```

Comment: This fails when there's a `<cc:interface componentType>` which the `<cc:implementation>` is relying upon.